# Header image on website not showing on mobile, what is the issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a personal website that has a header image that expands the width of the screen when testing the mobile responsiveness in google chrome it seems to work great but after deploying and viewing on mobile devices the image seems to either not show up. Could someone take a look into why this is? website is hosted on robbiechastain.com

Here is the CSS:

```
.hero {
  position: relative;
  background: url("images/laptop.png") no-repeat bottom fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 110px;
  min-height: 500px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: I am able to see the background image

Comment: On your mobile device? Do you have android? iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there nothing wrong with the css,  what caused it to seem like it not showing up is whether the size of your laptop.png image is large ( 2.2mb ) or because of the network connection which make the image take longer to load.

Anyway, you should always reduce the size of the image in order to improve your site performance

Comment: After further testing it seems the image is just extremely zoomed in.

Comment: Did you you adjust it with a fixed height in CSS ?

Comment: I have not yet been able to fix the issue.

Comment: As from my phone chrome browser, the robbiechastain.com look like this https://imgur.com/a/MfRlPDM, try to clear the image cached in your browser, or use img tool to edit this image, make it center, or you can look for css that adjust the background position. Hope this will help.

Comment: Im finding that mobile browsers on iPhone do not like the background image as "fixed"